# Flickable scrollbar malfunctioning

Tags: qml, scrollbar, flickable

I have created a TextArea inside a flickable, and when I add lots of newlines the area scrolls as expected.  However, although a scrollbar appears when I type more lines than the available height, if I try to drag the scrollbar it resets to fully colored (nothing to drag) and just generally misbehaves.

What is wrong with my scrollbar?

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    id: box
    width: 640
    height: 180
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("ScrollBar Mystery")

    Flickable {
        id: inputWrapper
        anchors.fill: parent

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            id: scrollBar
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            anchors.left: box.right
        }
        Keys.onUpPressed: scrollBar.decrease()
        Keys.onDownPressed: scrollBar.increase()

        clip: true
         flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
        function ensureVisible(r)
        {
            if (contentX >= r.x)
                contentX = r.x;
            else if (contentX+width <= r.x+r.width)
                contentX = r.x+r.width-width;
            if (contentY >= r.y)
                contentY = r.y;
            else if (contentY+height <= r.y+r.height)
                contentY = r.y+r.height-height;
        }
        TextEdit {
            id: input
            anchors.fill: parent
            text: ""
            focus: true
            wrapMode: TextEdit.Wrap
            onCursorRectangleChanged: inputWrapper.ensureVisible(cursorRectangle)
        }  // TextEdit
    }  // Flickable
}  // Window
```

Comment: what are Box and cursorRectangle? please put an example that can compile and test it.

Comment: CursorRectangle is a property of TextEdit: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#cursorRectangle-prop.  Box is just a parent box I dropped this into, but you can put inside your own object

Comment: I replaced with a complete working example

Comment: Thanks @TSG , check answer it works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forget to set `contentHeight` and `contentWidth`

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    id: box
    width: 640
    height: 180
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("ScrollBar Mystery")

    Flickable {
        id: inputWrapper
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentHeight: input.implicitHeight
        contentWidth:  input.implicitWidth

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            id: scrollBar
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            anchors.left: box.right
        }
        Keys.onUpPressed: scrollBar.decrease()
        Keys.onDownPressed: scrollBar.increase()

        clip: true
         flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
        function ensureVisible(r)
        {
            if (contentX >= r.x)
                contentX = r.x;
            else if (contentX+width <= r.x+r.width)
                contentX = r.x+r.width-width;
            if (contentY >= r.y)
                contentY = r.y;
            else if (contentY+height <= r.y+r.height)
                contentY = r.y+r.height-height;
        }
        TextEdit {
            id: input
            anchors.fill: parent
            text: ""
            focus: true
            wrapMode: TextEdit.Wrap
            onCursorRectangleChanged: inputWrapper.ensureVisible(cursorRectangle)
        }  // TextEdit
    }  // Flickable
}  // Window
```

[image]

Comment: This works so I'll accept it.  Just to point out to others, if your flickable does not fill to parent, you get binding errors in the scrollbar.  Workaround is to set x/y/height/width and then scrollbar works.